# listbox.valuemember throws exception

Tags: vb.net

I have this simple code:

```
 ListBox1.DataSource = MGlobals.UserList

ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome"

ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

when setting .ValueMember i get "

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Não é possível vincular ao novo membro de apresentação.
Nome do parâmetro: newDisplayMember
```

"

debugging i found `ListBox1.ValueMember` holding `""` and `ListBox1.DisplayMember` holding `"ID"`. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a SelectedIndexChanged event handler? Note that setting the DataSource triggers the SelectedIndexChanged while the ValueMember and DisplayMember are not still set. Then setting the DisplayMember causes another call to SelectedIndexChanged. Always set the DataSource after display and value member

Comment: i don't have a SelectedIndexChanged event handler but the order switch solved it. thanks @Steve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datasource Does have the Nome and ID columns, you could try changing the order to something like this:

```
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome"
ListBox1.ValueMember   = "ID"
ListBox1.DataSource    = MGlobals.UserList
```

Comment: Please check the answer as answered, Thanks